# Unable to add in bulk the guest users to AAD groups, whereas I can add them manually one at a time

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Unable to add in bulk the guest users to AAD groups, whereas can I add them manually one at a time. In the same bulk update I can add the internal AAD user but for guest user it throws out an error as below.  It throw out the error that user does not exist.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried adding guest users in bulk to AAD group, please check if you followed below steps:

- Ensure that you have guest users in your tenant.
- To invite guest users in bulk, make use of **`UserInviteTemplate`** and add email address of guest users in it and upload it.
- To check whether that bulk operation is successful or not,  ***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Users -> Bulk Operation Results -> See the status***
- Filter the users based on '***Guest***' Usertype and check guest users.
- To add these guest users to AAD group, create one group in ***Azure AD -> Groups***
- To add guest users as members of that group, follow below:
  ***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Groups -> Members -> Bulk Operations -> Import Members***

[image]

- Download **`GroupImportMembersTemplate`** and add **object IDs** of guest users in that excel and upload the file.

[image]

- You can also add **UPNs** of guest users in place of **object IDs**.
- Users added successfully, see the snapshot below:

[image]

If you add any other instead of **Object ID** or **UPN** of guest users in that excel, bulk operation will fail with error like below:

> **No user with this user name/object ID exists in this group. Change the
> user name/object ID in the file to match the user name/object ID of an
> existing user in this group and resubmit your request.**

***To know more in detail, please refer the below links:***

[Where do I go to troubleshoot problems? · Issue #52825 · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/52825?msclkid=e2da53acbeda11eca1f9acc4ffc26c7e)

[Unable to bulk import B2B guest users · Issue #56933 · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/56933?msclkid=d2280914bed811ec97f009bbb87aa4a3)

[Bulk upload to add or create members of a group - Azure Active Directory | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-bulk-import-members#feedback)

Answer (score 0):

How to add Guest Users in AAD individually:

1. Go to https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/r#/groups
2. Page should display in two columns: "Groups I own" (left-hand column) and "Groups I'm in (right-hand column)
3. Select the name of the Azure Active Directory Group that you own, that you want to add a user to
4. Click on the "+" at the end of the table (table headers include: "Members" (Names), "Role", "ID" (email), "+")

You can add guest users individually by email ID or name